# Configurable product on back-end In Stock but in frontend showing Out of Stock

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

I have a strange problem. In the backend I configured a configurable product with a simple product and assigned stock to the simple product.

[image]

Also the product has the status In Stock

[image]

But the add to cart option is not displaying on the website. Any idea why ?

Comment: Website url example: http://byhilkenl.hypernode.io/broeken-21/by-hilke-happy-pants-pink.html

Comment: Anyone any idea ?